# Use of ENUMs in Grails Domain Class

Tags: grails, enums, grails-orm

There are a few examples of ENUM on Grails (here in SO as well), but I am not being able to get the desired results.

Solutions include
1) By having the ENUM in a separate class under the src/groovy
*Domain Class*

```
class Offer {
    PaymentMethod acceptedPaymentMethod 
    ..
}
```

*src/groovy* PaymentMethod

```
public enum PaymentMethod {
    BYBANKTRANSFERINADVANCE('BANKADVANCE'),
    BYINVOICE('ByInvoice'),
     CASH('Cash'),
    CHECKINADVANCE('CheckInAdvance'),
    PAYPAL('PayPal'),
    String id

    PaymentMethod(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

In this case the Enum Class is not recognized at all at the domain class issuing an error. Looked like this used to work for Grails prior to version 2.

Am I missing something here? How to use external ENUM class in a domain in Grails?

2) Place ENUM within the domain class.

In this case the grails does not complain while compiling, but the scaffolding does not include any info the ENUM values (it is like the property acceptedPaymentMethod is not included at all in the scaffolding process)
Example:

```
class Offer {
    PaymentMethod acceptedPaymentMethod 
    ..
    enum PaymentMethod {
        BYBANKTRANSFERINADVANCE('BANKADVANCE'),
        BYINVOICE('ByInvoice'),
        CASH('Cash'),
        CHECKINADVANCE('CheckInAdvance'),
        PAYPAL('PayPal'),
        String id

        PaymentMethod(String id) {
            this.id = id
        }
    }
}
```

Checking the structure of the DB Table, the field is not an ENUM but a simple VarChar:

```
| accepted_payment_method        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Is there support for ENUMs on Grails Gorm at all?

Comment: Scaffolding is an utility provided to gorm domain classes only not if you nest them or put enum into them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried with Grails 2.3.4 and it worked with the *src/groovy* approach:

#### src/groovy/PaymentMethod.groovy

```
public enum PaymentMethod {
    BYBANKTRANSFERINADVANCE('BANKADVANCE'),
    BYINVOICE('ByInvoice'),
     CASH('Cash'),
    CHECKINADVANCE('CheckInAdvance'),
    PAYPAL('PayPal'),
    String id

    PaymentMethod(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

#### grails-app/domain/CustomDomain.groovy

```
class CustomDomain {
  PaymentMethod acceptedPaymentMethod
}
```

Then I ran `grails generate-all CustomDomain`, and here's the `_form.gsp` it generated:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: customDomain, field: 'acceptedPaymentMethod', 'error')} required">
    <label for="acceptedPaymentMethod">
        <g:message code="customDomain.acceptedPaymentMethod.label" default="Accepted Payment Method" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select name="acceptedPaymentMethod" from="${custombinds.PaymentMethod?.values()}" keys="${custombinds.PaymentMethod.values()*.name()}" required="" value="${customDomain?.acceptedPaymentMethod?.name()}"/>
</div>
```

Note that in Grails 2.3.x the scaffold feature was transformed into a plugin, so you need to include the following in your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
```

Comment: Thx for the response! It turns out you are right! Had some problems that where solved by running grails clean and regenerating again the classes. For some strange reason the IDE (GGTS) shows an error in the domain class invocation of the ENUM (not recognized) but this is IDE related as the app compiles fine from commandline.

Comment: @Armand Yeah, GGTS sometimes will underscore your attribute but that doesn't mean that your code is incorrect. In dynamic languages like Groovy it's better to cover this things with unit tests (if the test is ok, probably your code is correct).

Comment: how the insert will happen for the domain class "CustomDomain"? I mean how the control will from View ->Controller ->Service->Domain class ?

Comment: found some useful information here : https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/groovy-and-grails/Home/gorm-and-domain-object-modeling/domain-object-modeling-with-groovy-enums

Answer (score 2):

Since GORM 6.1 IdentityEnumType handling changed. In order to store enum by id and not by name or ordial use

```
static mapping = {
  myEnum enumType:"identity"
}
```