# enums in grails - persisting enum values to domain classes

Tags: grails, enums, grails-orm

I have created enum class UserType  under `/src/groovy/` as:

```
public enum UserType {
    USER(1),
    DEVSADMIN(2),
    RESTAURANTADMIN(3)
}
```

My Domain class "User" is  like :

```
class User {
    String  firstName
    String  lastName
    String  emailAddress
    String  contactNumber
    String  password
    String  image
    Date    dateOfBirth

    UserType userType
```

Still  my domain class having user_type field of string type not enum.Also I would like to know about,how can I persist data for domain class USER in which user_type is enum?

Looking for short example which will have enum groovy class,domain class,controller and service.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20540484/2166188

Comment: Before posting this question, I had look at it.But the service part is missing in that answer which is am looking at.

Comment: got what I was looking for here : https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/groovy-and-grails/Home/gorm-and-domain-object-modeling/domain-object-modeling-with-groovy-enums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a workaround for my problem:
I have created a enum class "UserType" at **path : src/groovy/**

Enum Class **UserType** looks like  :

```
public enum UserType {
USER('user'),
DEVSADMIN('devsAdmin'),
RESTAURANTADMIN('restaurantAdmin')
String id

UserType(String id){
    this.id = id
 }
}
```

**Domain class "User"** in which I am using the above enum class as:

```
class User {
String  firstName
String  lastName
String  emailAddress
String  contactNumber
String  password
String  image
Date    dateOfBirth

UserType userType
static constraints = {
    userType blank : false
  }
 }
```

**enum handling  in controller :**

```
class AuthenticationController {

def authenticationService

def userRegistration(){
    Date date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd","1991-01-08")
    authenticationService.userSignUp(   "Abhinandan", "Satpute", abhinandan.satpute@gmail.com", "8796105046", "123", "abc_image",
            date, UserType.RESTAURANTADMIN)
 }
}
```

**Persisting enum values using Service:**

```
class AuthenticationService {

def userSignUp(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress, String contactNumber, String password, String image,
               Date dateOfBirth, Enum userType){

    User user   =   new User("firstName" : firstName, "lastName" : lastName, "emailAddress" : emailAddress, "contactNumber" :contactNumber,
            "password" : password, "image" : image, "dateOfBirth" : dateOfBirth, "userType" : userType)
    user.save(flush: true)
 }
}
```

Finally , schema of table "User" looks like : 
In this table "user_type" is the enum field which stored as VARCHAR in domain class.
[image: schema of table "User" looks like]
After inserting record  to user table :
[image: after inserting record]